# SQL Editor / Viewer for Mac

Tags: mysql, sql, macos, codehighlighter, code-hinting

Im looking good SQL (MySQL) editor/viewer for MacOS. I want to spend money on it, if it what I looking for. (on Windows I use: dbForge Mysql and I looking something similar to it)

Main features I need:

- Code hinting
- Code highlighting
- Hinting on writing procedure and functions

I'm not interested in: SequelPro (it is too light, no code hinting, no procedure making enviroment)
Not interested in Navicat and MySQL Workbench.

I have tried these tools and it's all ugly. (I need to write more and more procedures and functions, and I need good code hinting like in dbForge)

Please, help to find it :/

Comment: I wonder if you could expand on what you meant by 'good'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried DBvisualizer?

http://www.dbvis.com/products/dbvis/download/

Olivier

Comment: Oh thanks Olivier! Looks pretty good for me. But too bad it is Java, and it is using jdbc. And it doesn't have built-in ssh tunneling. But I use ssh -L, but..  Thank you Olivier! :)